# Clicks not passed through to custom component in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm including a bunch of posts like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="posts">
    <div id="posts-wrapper">
      <post v-for="(item, key) in posts" :key="item.id" :post="item" :isListItem="true"></post>
    </div>
    <infinite-loading :on-infinite="onInfinite" ref="infiniteLoading">
      <span slot="no-more">
        There are no more posts
      </span>
    </infinite-loading>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading'
import posts from '@/api/posts'
import post from '@/components/Post'

export default {
  name: 'posts',
  components: {
    post,
    InfiniteLoading,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInfinite() {
        posts.getPosts(page++).then(posts => {
        this.posts = this.posts.concat(posts);
        this.$refs.infiniteLoading.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:loaded');
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is the `post` component:

```
<template>
  <v-card class="post-list-item" v-bind:class="{ clickable: isListItem }" @click.native="openPost">
    <div class="header">
      {{ post.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="image">

    </div>
    <div class="data">

    </div>
    <!-- same handler bound here just for testing -->
    <div class="button" v-on:click.native="openPost">
      Open post
    </div>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'post',
    methods: {
      openPost() {
        console.log('post opening');
      }
    },
    props: {
      post: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      isListItem: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that the clicks are not passed through, ie. the `openPost()` method is never called. If I set a listener in the parent, then that works, but is not what I'm looking for. The clicks should be handled within the component itself.

The `v-card` is a [Vuetify component](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/cards).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't get anything in the console?

Comment: @thanksd Nope, nothing. The component renders otherwise fine too, and lifecycle hooks fire as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i solved it by using

```
v-on:click
```

instead of

```
@click.native
```